# Prevent other users from ejecting (or even seeing) my mounted disk images

Tags: finder, mount, dmg, privacy

I have an encrypted disk image (sparsebundle) where all of my private documents are stored; I mount it to a custom mount point with:

```
mkdir -p /Users/gabriele/MyDocs
hdiutil attach /MyDocs.sparsebundle -mountpoint /Users/gabriele/MyDocs
```

Other users see the mounted disk image in the Finder window sidebar and maybe also on their Desktops (according to Finder preferences), but they cannot access the volume because of unsufficient privileges. In any case other users can eject the volume, and this is bad.

Is there a way to prevent other users from ejecting my volumes, or even seeing this volume if they don't have enough privileges to view its innards?

Answer (score 2):

To help make the mounted disk image less visible, you can run the SetFile command to make the volume's directory invisible. This will make the mounted disk image be less-obviously visible in the Finder sidebar for other users. Of course, this makes it less visible to you, too, but you can make an alias in the Finder to where the folder should be for you.

Run SetFile to make the mounted disk image image be invisible in the Finder:

```
SetFile -a V /Users/gabriele/MyDocs
```

Open the disk image location in the Finder:

```
open /Users/gabriele/MyDocs
```

Make an alias to make it easy for you to open the now-hidden MyDocs. Within the open Finder window, grab the folder icon in the top center where it says "MyDocs" and then drag that while holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd> keys and release it on your Desktop, just not to `/Users/gabriele`, because you will need to rename the alias first, otherwise it will not let you copy it. So rename the dragged-off "MyDoc" to "MyDoc alias", then move it to `/Users/gabriele` or wherever you like. Now you should have the alias "MyDoc alias" to your hidden MyDoc directory, other users will not see it in the Finder sidebar.

Note: Xcode needs to be installed in order to use SetFile. Additionally, I had to relaunch the Finder on Lion for the mounted disk image to become invisible, try that if you can't get MyDoc to disappear.

Not sure how to prevent ejection, since anyone with access to Disk Utility, the `mount` command, etc. can see the path to it and un-mount it for you. However, making it invisible does lessen the need to make it un-ejectable, since it will not be in other users' faces in the Finder as an option to eject.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and eventually get back… :)

Comment: Ok, here I am after a test drive… if the directory is invisible it cannot be indexed nor searched by Spotlight: this is a huge drawback to me, because I have tons of documents in there. Furthermore, any unprivileged user to such Volume can still eject it, from the Finder if they toggle invisible files/directories to show up, or even from the command line prior easily identifying any mounted devices. There should be a way to prevent unmounting Volumes you don't have any access to, unless being root or listed among sudoers. Am I asking too much? :-)

Comment: I use MacFUSE and SSHFS to mount _remote_ disks locally.  The mount points are directories visible to everyone but owned by me.  When mounted, the directories disappear from Finder for other users.  In the shall, `ls` of the parents shows the directory, but trying to `ls` gets "no such file or directory" and trying to `mount` gets "not mounted."  BUT I DO NOT KNOW whether this can be used for a locally connected disk.

Comment: Tried to relieve my ignorance with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431393/can-macfuse-ssh-be-used-to-mount-a-locally-connected-disk-or-dmg