# Can MACFUSE & SSH be used to mount a locally connected disk or DMG?

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I have a website that I maintain mounted locally using [macFUSE and SSHFS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/prevent-other-users-from-ejecting-or-even-seeing-my-mounted-disk-images).  I am wondering whether both or macFUSE alone can mount a locally connected external disk?  This might be useful for [preventing other users from accessing or dismounting the disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/prevent-other-users-from-ejecting-or-even-seeing-my-mounted-disk-images).